# socat pipe to pipe for multiple open-write-close and open-read-close operations

Tags: tar, netcat, socat

I'm trying to use socat on two systems in order to send a multivolume tar from one system to the other. Multivolume is an absolute requirement as I'm trying to shift potentially petabytes of data to a mounted tape archive.

Ultimately, I'm want to do something like this:

```
#  on system1:
socat PIPE:/tmp/pipe1 SYSTEM:"ssh system2 socat - PIPE\:/tmp/pipe2" &
tar -M -L 10G -F /tmp/chvol -cvf /tmp/pipe1 <source-path> &

#  on system2:
cat /tmp/pipe2 > file001.tar
cat /tmp/pipe2 > file002.tar
...
```

(The chvol script just echos the path /tmp/pipe1.)

As I've not been able to get this working yet, I'm running the following much-simplified test on one single system:

```
socat PIPE:/tmp/pipe1 PIPE:/tmp/pipe2 &
sh -c 'while sleep 1; do echo "sending date ..."; date > /tmp/pipe1; done' &
sh -c 'while sleep 1; do echo "slurping ..."; cat < /tmp/pipe2; done' &
```

which is meant to simulate a writer process repeatedly opening, writing, closing and a reader process repeatedly opening, reading until EOF, closing.

But this doesn't behave as I expected: the writer is seemingly happy, but the reader reads all the accumulated text in one go and thereafter remains blocked in a `cat < ...` call.

Can anybody explain (1) what is actually happening in the much-simplified test and (2) what I should be doing instead?

I have tried various `shut-*` options on both pipes (on the assumption that the problem is in the propogation of EOF) and done a lot of googling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you have not specified you want unidirectional pipes.  The socat man page explains how in this case `PIPE:` is like an echo.

What probably happened is that when you first wrote the date into the fifo 1, your `socat` read it, wrote it to fifo 2, then noticed there was input on fifo 2 so read it and wrote it to fifo 1, and so on busy looping until the first `cat` on fifo 2 managed to empty it before socat read it.  Thereafter this first `cat` will continue reading the fifo, never seeing an end-of-file, and you can continue writing the date into the fifo.

You can see this if you add the `-v` option to socat to show the i/o.

Adding `-u` for unidirectional i/o makes it what you probably wanted, but now the `socat` will exit after the date is written and read, so you will need a loop for it:

```
while socat -v -u PIPE:/tmp/pipe1 PIPE:/tmp/pipe2; do echo new; done &
```

With your `tar` version you could put the `socat` command inside the `/tmp/chvol` script instead.

---

If you have a real tape drive, you might also look at a solution using [nbd-server](https://github.com/NetworkBlockDevice/nbd) to export a block device over the network.

Comment: I didn't realise that socat's reading of data from fifo1 and writing it to fifo2 made fifo2 readable **by socat**; I assumed that my own reader process (cat, in my much-simplified example) would be the only process reading. But your explanation fits! Many thanks Meuh!